# Error deleting Azure Directory - associated with existing Trial Subscription which is owned by a deleted account

Tags: azure, entra-id

Steps taken so far:

- Created a new Azure Organizational account called:
  name@company.onmicrosoft.com
- Started a Free Azure Trial, with credit
  card details. This created a single Directory with the new account as
  the only user.
- Realised I had made a mistake, decided I wanted to
  delete this new account/directory/subscription.

Followed advice here http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2967860

- Made my other personal account a Global Admin for the Directory (forgot to make it Co-Admin of the Free Trial Subscription)
- Logged in with my personal account
- Deleted the original name@company.onmicrosoft.com user from the Directory
- Attempted to delete the Directory, but error saying its still associated with the Free Trial Subscription
- Unable to continue as the original account has been deleted so there is no way to Cancel the Free Trial Subscription
- Even tried recreating the original account under the Directory, but it was no longer associated with the Free Trial Subscription.

This is a problem as I need to re-create the Directory (most importantly with its associated sub-domain) under another account. Help?

Comment: I would open a ticket with MS

Comment: Thanks, I have done, just wondered if anyone knew of a way round this. What's compounding the issue is the ticket really belongs with the deleted account, making it difficult to raise it!

Allowing you to delete a user with an active subscription seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dealt with Azure Billing Support, and the below was the eventual solution:

1. Create a new empty organization account under the Directory, with no
   subscriptions
2. From the corporate email address associated with the deleted account that originally created the Directory and owned the Trial Subscription, email Azure Billing Support formally requesting that ownership is transferred to the new empty account
3. Log in with the new account which now has ownership, make my company's official Azure account a Global Admin of the Directory
4. Log in with my company's account, transfer the Directory to our PAYG subscription
5. Log back in with the the new account, Cancel the Trial Subscription and remove my personal Hotmail account from the Directory

Answer (score 0):

If you added your personal account (Microsoft Account) as a global admin to the directory, then in you go to a subscription where this account is administrator (of the subscription), then you should be able to access the directory. The existence of the trial subscription should not give you any problems because your personal account can already manage the directory.

Comment: Thanks, yes I could access the Directory, but I wanted to delete it, which I couldn't do as it was still on the Trial Subscription and I couldn't change the subscription. Eventual solution below.